# Как авторизовать Telegram app через python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pyrogram

Подскажите как авторизовать приложение и получить данные
через pyrogram или посредством Telegram API вида

```
{"id": id, "first_name": first_name, "auth_date": auth_date, "hash": hash}
```

Мой подход таков

1. С помощью Telegram API отправляю запрос => ввод номера телефона и отправка кода
   В этот момент начинают лететь запросы на /login и ответов false
   а) в pyrogram подтверждаю вход нажатием кнопки confirm
   После этого пытаюсь получить данные но мне пишет что сессия истекла хотя прошло не более 10 секунд. Я так понимаю если не происходит отправки post запроса то сессия сразу разрывается

Но не до конца понимаю как все-таки авторизоваться в приложении и получить data-onauth

Вот код для отправки
Запрос для отправки кода

```
params = {
    'bot_id': '6190046558',
    'origin': 'https://galxe.com',
    'request_access': 'write',
    'return_to': 'https://galxe.com/accountSetting?tab=SocialLinlk',
}

data = {
    'phone': phone,
}

response = session.post('https://oauth.telegram.org/auth/request', params=params, headers=headers,data=data)
```

код для постоянных запросов (видимо проверка авторизации)

```
    response = requests.post('https://oauth.telegram.org/auth/login?bot_id=6190046558&origin=https://galxe.com&request_access=write&return_to=https://galxe.com/accountSetting?tab=SocialLinlk', headers=headers, data=data)
```

Код для подтверждения входа через приложение

```
headers = {
    'authority': 'oauth.telegram.org',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'origin': 'https://galxe.com',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="115", "Chromium";v="115"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

data = {
    'bot_id': '6190046558',
}

response = requests.post('https://oauth.telegram.org/auth/get', headers=headers, data=data)
```

Пытался одновременно запустить получение pyrogram - подтверждение кода (Acept) и постоянные запросы для сохранения авторизации = безрезультатно. Буду благодарен если подскажите как можно авторизовать приложение